# nix overlay for bundler

Tags: nix, nixos

I would like to create a nix overlay for the Ruby `bundler` package, as the version currently upstream in nixpkgs (unstable) is for an older version than I require:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/bundler/default.nix

I'm attempting to run a local derivation called `foo` in a nix-shell, that depends on on a newer version of `bundler`:

./custom_packages.nix:

```
{ system ? builtins.currentSystem }:

# Pinning Nixpkgs to a specific version.
let
  hostPkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  pinnedVersion = hostPkgs.lib.importJSON ./nixpkgs-version.json;
  pinnedPkgs = hostPkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "NixOS";
    repo = "nixpkgs-channels";
    inherit (pinnedVersion) rev sha256;
  };

in
  with import pinnedPkgs {overlays = [
    (self: super: {
      bundler = self.callPackage ./pkgs/bundler/1_16_1 {};
    })
  ];};

rec {
  foo = callPackage ./pkgs/foo { };
}
```

./nixpkgs-version.json

```
{
  "url": "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs-channels.git",
  "rev": "a66ce38acea505c4b3bfac9806669d2ad8b34efa",
  "date": "2018-03-04T07:45:36+00:00",
  "sha256": "1jrz6lkhx64mvm0h4gky9b6iaazivq69smppkx33hmrm4553dx5h",
  "fetchSubmodules": true
}
```

./pkgs/bundler/1_16_1/default.nix:

```
{ buildRubyGem, makeWrapper, ruby, coreutils }:

buildRubyGem rec {
  inherit ruby;
  name = "${gemName}-${version}";
  gemName = "bundler";
  version = "1.16.1";
  sha256 = "1s2nq4qnffxg3kwrk7cnwxcvfihlhxm9absl2l6d3qckf3sy1f22";
  dontPatchShebangs = true;

  postFixup = ''
    sed -i -e "s/activate_bin_path/bin_path/g" $out/bin/bundle
  '';
}
```

./pkgs/foo/default.nix:

```
{ mkShell, bundler }:

mkShell rec {
  name = "scribble-${version}";
  version = "1.0.0-beta";
  buildInputs = [bundler];
}
```

Run nix shell:

```
$ nix-shell ./custom_packages.nix -A foo --command "bundle --version" --pure
```

Attempting to run `foo` in a nix-shell produces an error when building `bundler`, this informs me that bundler has: `attribute ‘source’ missing`. This suggests to me that I'm incorrectly identifying bundler as a "standard" derivation - but clearly it's not. At a guess I think using `callPackage` may be the wrong thing to do when defining my overlay - but I'm unsure of an alternative approach.

Can anyone please advise how I can overlay `bundler` with a newer version (ideally using overlays).

FYI: I'm using nix package manager on macOS 10.12.6

Thanks

Comment: What's in your `nixpkgs-version.json`?

Comment: @RobertHensing updated the question with this info

Comment: The `source` attribute was missing in your argument to `buildRubyGem` in your bundler `default.nix`. You can fix that problem by changing the `sha256` attribute to `source.sha256`. That's a change between 17.09 and unstable/18.03

Comment: The next problem seems to be related to `buildRubyGems` automatic binary wrappers. Perhaps you could try #nixos on IRC and/or file an issue on nixpkgs.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHensing, adding `source.sha256` to my `bundler` derivation did the trick (happy to mark this as correct answer if you add it).
I believe the next error you were seeing was related to the fact that `foo/default.nix` was not defining a valid `buildPhase`.
I have updated the question to include a valid `foo/default.nix`. Running `foo` inside a nix-shell shows my specified version of bundler is installed.
I can't seem to find any docs on using `source.sha256` - is its use specific to `buildRubyGem`?  I'm wondering how using `source.sha256` differs from using a `src` attribute?

Comment: Yes, `source.sha256` is specific to `buildRubyGem` and sadly it hasn't been documented. I suppose it's a work in progress... The `source` attribute is used when `src` is missing. Here's the code that's responsible: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/1bc5bf4beb759e563ffc7a8a3067f10a00b45a7d/pkgs/development/ruby-modules/gem/default.nix#L54

Comment: Thanks @RobertHensing for the additional info and your help.